# Obtain the list of dependency files for a target depending on files?

Tags: cmake, buildconfiguration

I have a custom CMake target which looks like this:

```
add_custom_target(foo ALL DEPENDS subdir/f1 anotherdir/f2 f3)
```

Now, I want to write a loop such as the following:

```
foreach(some_file MAGIC_GOES_HERE)
    # Do stuff with ${some_file}
endforeach()
```

which will loop over the three files which `foo` depends on. Note: I would prefer these to be paths rather than just strings, i.e. `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/subdir/f1`, `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/anotherdir/f2` or `./subdir/f1` and `./anotherdir/f2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better options out there, but you can create your own wrapper for `add_custom_target` and capture the dependencies like this:

```
function(my_add_custom_target)
    # extract DEPENDS argument
    set(_MULTI_VALUE_ARGS DEPENDS)
    cmake_parse_arguments(
        CUSTOM_TARGET "" ""
        "${_MULTI_VALUE_ARGS}"
        ${ARGN}
    )

    # export to parent scope
    list(GET ARGN 0 TARGET_NAME)
    string(TOUPPER ${TARGET_NAME} TARGET_NAME)
    set("${TARGET_NAME}_DEPS" "${CUSTOM_TARGET_DEPENDS}" PARENT_SCOPE)

    # continue with regular cmake
    add_custom_target(${ARGN})
endfunction()
```

then you can use it in your cmake:

```
my_add_custom_target(custom ALL DEPENDS subdir/f1 anotherdir/f2 f3)

foreach(dep ${CUSTOM_DEPS})
    message(STATUS "dependency: ${dep}")
    # or whatever...
endforeach()
```